# The existence of the normal subgroups of GF($2^m$) under addition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

If we construct our GF($2^4$) with primitive polynomial $\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ where $\alpha$ is the primitive element in extended Galois field GF($2^4$). The elements of the GF($2^4$) generated by $\alpha$ as such $\{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5,\alpha^6,\alpha^7,\alpha^8,\alpha^9,\alpha^{10},\alpha^{11},\alpha^{12},\alpha^{13},\alpha^{14}\}$. I am interested to know if there exist a subgroup under addition operation (not multiplication). More so if there is a "normal" subgroup under addition. One possible additive subgroup that I found is $\{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^4\}$. Why there is little on additive property of GF($2^4$). All the literature talks about multiplicative (normal) subgroups etc. ?

Comment: The addition in any ring, hence field, is commutative.  Thus _any_ subgroup is normal.  You could perhaps use Cauchy's theorem to get a subgroup.

Comment: ${\rm GF}(2^4)$ under addition has a total of $67$ subgroups, with $1,15,35,15,1$ subgroups of order $2^i$ for $0 \le i \le 4$.

Comment: Chris: So the subgroup $\{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^4\}$ is a normal subgroup of order 4. Since by definition a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ to be normal should satisfy $x + a + x^{-1} \in H$ for all $a \in H$ and $x \in G$. I have checked it DOES satisfy the condition if we assume $H \in \{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^4\}$, then let us just take $\alpha^9 \in G$, then  $\alpha^9 + \alpha + \alpha^9 = \alpha \in H$ since the additive inverse of $\alpha^9$ is itself.

Comment: Therefore, $\{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^4\}$ is a normal subgroup with cosets $\{\alpha^2, \alpha^8, \alpha^5, \alpha^{10}\}$,  $\{\alpha^{13}, \alpha^6, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{11}\}$ and $\{\alpha^{3}, \alpha^9, \alpha^{7}, \alpha^{14}\}$. Derek: You mentioned that there are $67$ subgroups under addition? Also, what is the procedure to find those subgroups,  at least for order of $4$ which you claim to have 35 subgroups?

Comment: SpiderMath, 35 is the number of 2-dimensional subspaces $W$ of a 4-dimensional space $V$ over $GF(2)$. Let's first count the number of orders bases of such subspaces. The first basis element $v_1$ can be selected in $15=2^4-1$ ways, any non-zero vector of $V$ will do. The second basis element $v_2$ can be anything other than $0$ or $v_1$, so $14$ choices for a total of $15\cdot14=210$ pairs $\{v_1,v_2\}$. How many such pairs will generate the same subspace $W$? Then $v_1$ can be any of the three non-zero vectors in $W$. As above, $v_2$ then has two alternatives for us not to leave $W$.

Comment: Thus the answer is that $3\cdot2=6$ pairs $\{v_1,v_2\}$ give rise to the same subspace $W$. This number is the same for all the subspaces. Hence the number of subspaces is $210/6=35$.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki Lahtonen for the explanation relating to subspaces. I actually found now all $35$ normal subgroups under addition. So, here there are $\{ 0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^4\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^2, \alpha^8\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^5, \alpha^{10}\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^6, \alpha^{13}\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^3, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^7, \alpha^9\}$, $\{ 0, 1, \alpha^{11}, \alpha^{12}\}$,  $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{2}, \alpha^{5}\}$,  $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{8}, \alpha^{10}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{13}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{9}\}$,

Comment: $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{7}, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha, \alpha^{6}, \alpha^{11}\}$,  $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{2}, \alpha^{10}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{5}, \alpha^{8}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{11}, \alpha^{13}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{7}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{9}, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^4, \alpha^{6}, \alpha^{12}\}$,  $\{ 0, \alpha^2, \alpha^{13}, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^2, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{6}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^2, \alpha^{7}, \alpha^{12}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^2, \alpha^{9}, \alpha^{11}\}$,  $\{ 0, \alpha^5, \alpha^{4}, \alpha^{13}\}$,

Comment: $\{ 0, \alpha^5, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{11}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^5, \alpha^{6}, \alpha^{9}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^5, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^8, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{13}\}$,$ \{ 0, \alpha^8, \alpha^{7}, \alpha^{11}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^8, \alpha^{9}, \alpha^{12}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^8, \alpha^{6}, \alpha^{14}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^{10}, \alpha^{9}, \alpha^{13}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^{10}, \alpha^{3}, \alpha^{12}\}$, $\{ 0, \alpha^{10}, \alpha^{6}, \alpha^{7}\}$, and $\{ 0, \alpha^{10}, \alpha^{11}, \alpha^{14}\}$.